# Angularjs - changing location.path from modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a angular modal window (for login). When user hits submit, i need to change the view to a home page (/myhome).

But doing $location.path = "/myhome" does not seem to be working from modal controller.

I open the Modal as follows:

```
  $scope.openLoginModal = function () {
             var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              templateUrl: 'resources/html/login.html',
              controller: 'loginController',
              windowClass: 'app-modal-window'
            });
              };
```

And in my loginController, when user hits Submit i invoke doLogin function:

```
myApp.controller('loginController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $location, $http) {
....

$scope.dologin = function () { 
...
    $location.path="/myhome";
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
....
}
```

#### Question

But the view never changes to /myhome. 
Any ideas? Or alternative ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting $location.path incorrectly. It's a setter function so the syntax is:

```
$location.path("/myhome");
```

Try that and see how it goes.